# How to rewrite Regex.Replace (due to async api)

Tags: c#, regex, async-await

I have a function ReplaceParameters that replaces values in a string by using Regex.Replace. This has been working fine, but now the api that gets replacement-string has become async-only. This is a repro of the current code:

```
public static string ReplaceParameters(string query)
{
    var result = Regex.Replace(query, @"(?<parameter>\|\w+\|)", ReplaceParameterEvaluator,
                                         RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

    return result;
}

private static string ReplaceParameterEvaluator(Match parameterMatch)
{
    var parameter = parameterMatch.Groups["parameter"].Value;
    return GetReplacement(parameter);
}

private static string GetReplacement(string parameter)
{
    //...
}
```

Since the (new) GetReplacement function now is returning a Task instead of string: `private static async Task<string> GetReplacementAsync(string parameter)` the ReplaceParameterEvaluator function can't be made compatible with the MatchEvaluator delegate.

Sinc this has to run on a web-server and not cause dead-locks, i cant use any of the dirty async-to-sync hacks like for example this: (use .Result) `var replacedQuery = Regex.Replace(query, @"(?<parameter>\|\w+\|)", match => ReplaceParameterEvaluatorAsync(match).Result, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);`

Is it possible to rewrite the function to find all the texts, and then replace them? Could Regex.Matches be used in some way?

(Seriously though, why is there not a Regex.ReplaceAsync function??)

Comment: Either don't use `GetReplacementAsync` or use "hacks". No elegant solution here.

Comment: Right after posting i found https://osdn.jp/projects/opentween/scm/git/open-tween/blobs/master/OpenTween/RegexAsync.cs - Which contains a simple implementation for RegexAsync.ReplaceAsync. But it does not support capture-groups. Perhaps a simliar aproach could be used in my case?

Comment: It seems to first match everything, then find replacements asynchronously and then replace everything. It's using regex twice, but yes, it's probably possible.

Comment: There is no `Regex.ReplaceAsync` function because string replacement is not an I/O bound operation, and exposing an async API wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski it CAN be an I/O bound operation though, in my case it's replacing `<img>` tags in HTML with base64 encoded image data read from disk. So - many hanks for your helpful answer below!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's simple enough to build your own extension method for this:

```
public static async Task<string> ReplaceAsync(this Regex regex, string input, Func<Match, Task<string>> replacementFn)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var lastIndex = 0;

    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
    {
        sb.Append(input, lastIndex, match.Index - lastIndex)
          .Append(await replacementFn(match).ConfigureAwait(false));

        lastIndex = match.Index + match.Length;
    }

    sb.Append(input, lastIndex, input.Length - lastIndex);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

It's straightforward:

- Copy unmatched chunks of text as-is to a `StringBuilder`
- Append the result of the callback function where text is matched

This is just a convenience method for calling async callbacks. It's not in the API because regex matching and replacement is a CPU-bound operation, which is naturally not asynchronous.

Comment: You could potentially even parallelize all the calls to `replacementFn` and then build the string at the end.

Comment: It's been some years since I last used the regex-classes... As you see in the original code, I'm using Regex.Replace (The static version) - Is it possible to change my code to use a Regex instance instead?

Comment: `new Regex(@"(?<parameter>\|\w+\|)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture).ReplaceAsync(...)`

Comment: @Rawling I would be careful with that. What if `replacementFn` is not thread-safe?

Comment: Tanks!
I have no problem with the regex not being cpu-bound. *My* function however *is*. - And you gave a nice workaround.

Comment: This is a great answer, but be careful when your regex is **RIGHT TO LEFT**

Comment: This method is not optimal as regardless of whether there are matches it would create a StringBuilder instance and copy text. It should check first if there are any matches and in such case where there are none, return input text.